# TestCafe - how to check number of test cases run in Runner class?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there a way to check the number of executed tests in the Runner class?
There are this ".then(failedCount => {" but this one only shows how many failed tests there are. I want to print the number of failed tests out of the total number of tests run, e.g. "2 / 10 test cases failed" where 2=failedCount and 10=totalNumberOfTestCases run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect output from the JSON reporter to a Writable Stream instance and then retrieve the desired information from the report. Check the following example (requires Node.js 8+)

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

(async () => {
    const testCafe   = await createTestCafe();
    let   reportData = '';

    await testCafe
        .createRunner()
        .src('test.js')
        .browsers('chrome')
        .reporter('spec')
        .reporter('json', { write: data => reportData += data.toString() })
        .run();

    const report = JSON.parse(reportData);

    console.log(`${report.total - report.passed}/${report.total} tests failed`);

    await testCafe.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. I took the info from junit xml report but this seem to be more clear